# Make image larger without losing quality in Paint.NET

Tags: images, resize, paint.net

I have an image that is a 3x5 photo.  We need to resize it to 12x15 and still need it to retain most, if not all, of it's image quality.

I do not have access to Photoshop, so I use Paint.NET.  From what I've personally experienced, when re-sizing an image, I always lose quality.  In this case, it's a very specific image and we need to make it larger and retain quality because it's all we have to go on for a project we are working on.

Comment: That question references Photoshop.  i don't have Photoshop and will not be obtaining it.  All I have access to is Paint.NET

Comment: Please read the chosen answer on the question, it's more general than the question, and it answers yours: basically, you can't.

Comment: This answer references the jpeg format, and basically non-vector based images.  We received the image in a word document and can basically copy the image into Paint.NET and save as any format we want.  I do not know the original format for the image however.  Will this rule still hold true if I save as a Tiff, PNG, bitmap, other?

Comment: The answer references any bitmap image -- any image built up by pixels, not vectors. An image from Word (bad habit, by the way, Word mangles images badly) has a limited amount of pixels you cannot increase without losing quality.

Comment: I agree with you about the sending in word.  Wouldn't do it myself, but it's how we received the image.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Quality is directly tied to the number of pixels in the image, not the print size. If you take an image that looks OK when printed and then triple the size you are either a) stretching each pixel to a larger square or; b) moving the pixels apart and inserting new pixels to fill the gaps. Both result in quality loss. The "safe" zone is about .75x-1.5x the original pixel size. For decent printing you want about 200-300 pixels for every inch. For 12 x 15, thats 3600 x 4500 pixels

Comment: I appreciate the information.  I'm not a graphic designer by trade, and generally only handle images that have been provided.  I do very little image generation/manipulation.

Comment: There are tons of questions related to this topic here. Try searching for "dpi raster scale".

Comment: Great information. Thanks.  I'd upvote your comment if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

ok, use a browser-based solution; off the top of my head you can use:
http://pixlr.com
which is like a flash-based, photoshop in your browser. if your on ios that's not going to work, moreover, sounds like overkill...all you need to do is convert the image file type. you can use google drive, or cloudconvert.org to accomplish this: go to either, upload your image, select the desired outcome, create the outcome. download the outcome. so you could change it to .gif, then resize the .gif file, which i think will fix the issue(s) you are seeing.