# Improving image quality

Tags: images, resize

I have an image (It is 474 x 162 px) and was asked to send it in the following formats. However, I have no design software and use Canva. I put in custom dimensions for 1200x628, 1200x1200, etc. and the image looks pixalated. What can I do?

Landscape (1.91:1): 1200×628 (min required: 600×314)
Square: 1200×1200 (min required: 300×300)

Landscape (4:1): 1200×300 (min required: 512×128)
Square: 1200×1200 (min required: 128×128)

Comment: What size is the original image?

Comment: Don't laugh. I had to open it in paint. It is 474 W and 162 H and 96 DPI.

Comment: You *can't* get a decent quality image by enlarging it more than 2, 3, 4 times. It will **always** look pixelated. What you are trying is impossible even with "design software".

Comment: See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-jpeg-without-losing-quality

Comment: I have a PDF that looks large, let me figure out what its size is.

Comment: Scott, I have a PDF of it and I opened it in Adobe and its 247.KB. Can I make this any of the sizes listed above?

Comment: Size on disk says incredibly little.

Comment: Adobe what? `:)` Adobe makes upwards of 25 different applications. Unfortunately, there's no way to tell anything about the quality of an image by looking at its file size (kb). It is **equally** possible that a ~250kb PDF contains a high quality vector image... or a very low quality raster image.

Comment: It can't be done. You will never get "improved" quality by enlarging a raster image. The quality will always be worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increase the size of a .jpeg without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-jpeg-without-losing-quality)

Answer (score 4):

It is simply *not* possible to enlarge a *raster* image 2, 3, 4 times its size or more and retain overall quality. In all cases there will be quality loss. The greater the enlargement, the more quality loss generally occurs.

What software you use for such an enlargement is typically irrelevant. The nature of the transformation is inherently bad based up *how* raster images (jpg, png) are constructed.

This is, admittedly, a generalization. However, pixel-based images by nature are not designed to retain quality if they are enlarged.

- Some software, such as Photoshop, may [interpolate](http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-resample-images-in-photoshop-cs6/) pixel data making *minor* enlargements acceptable.
- *Some* output methods don't require high-quality images (billboards, banners, etc).
- Small images with a *high* PPI (pixels per inch) setting can often be enlarged while lowering the PPI, creating acceptable results.

For more information see here:

- [How can I increase the size of a .jpeg without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-jpeg-without-losing-quality)
- [Make image larger without losing quality in Paint.NET](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30508/make-image-larger-without-losing-quality-in-paint-net)
- [How to resize an image without losing quality](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/how-to-resize-an-image-without-losing-quality)
- [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)